# Validating an email address on key-press using javascript & jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to prevent users from inputting invalid characters when typing-in an email address.  I am **NOT** trying to validate the entire value as-a-whole (that happens later).

**I "thought" this was the correct way to prevent a list of characters (such as # or $):**

```
/[A-Z0-9a-z@]^[$#<>?]/
```

**This part works:**

```
/[A-Z0-9a-z@]/
```

**This part fails:**

```
/^[$#<>?]/
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Any character is allowed in an email address if properly quoted, according to the specification. This code is going to block users with valid email addresses.

Comment: Your regex needs to get a bit more complicated than that to properly validate email addresses: http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: @Graham thank you. However, I'm not trying to validate the text as-a-whole (that happens later).

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. Create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem. When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIXED:**
The problem was some keynum values collide with undesirable characters.  This fixed it!

```
// **********************
// .emailOnly
// Use -
// Makes the element email-only.
//
// Example -
// $('.myElement').emailOnly();
// **********************
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        emailOnly: function() {
            return this.each(function() {
                return $(this).keypress(function(e, text) {

                    var keynum;
                    var keychar;
                    var regEx;
                    var allowedKeyNums = [8, 9, 35, 36, 46]; // Backspace, Tab, End, Home, (Delete & period)

                    if (window.event) // IE
                        keynum = e.keyCode;
                    else if (e.which) // Netscape/Firefox/Opera
                        keynum = e.which;
                    else
                        keynum = e.keyCode

                    keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
                    regEx = /[^$#<>?]/ // Undesirable characters

                    // Test for keynum values that collide with undesirable characters
                    if ($.inArray(keynum, allowedKeyNums) > -1)
                        return regEx.test(keychar);

                    regEx = /[A-Z0-9a-z@]/
                    return regEx.test(keychar);
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5):

Try `/[^$#<>?]/` instead.

The `^` **inside** and at directly after the opening bracket makes the class negative.

You can learn more about this on [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Or better, heres a workign simple regex that does it, using yours as a start.

http://jsfiddle.net/hG99U/1/

Comment: As noted above, the carat `^` needs to go inside the brackets and if you're only trying to prevent the invalid characters, there is no need for the `[A-Z0-9a-z@]` (which is an incomplete list of valid characters for email anyway)

Comment: Oddly, using regEx = /[A-Z0-9a-z@][^$#<>?]/ still allows the #$ to pass-through?

Comment: Yeah see, you're regex doesn't include repeaters and doesn't check where the @ should be or that there should be at least one dot + tld on the end :http://jsfiddle.net/hG99U/1/

Comment: I'm not trying to validate the text as-a-whole (that happens later).  I'm preventing invalid characters from going in.

Comment: In that case, this works like a charm for me: http://jsfiddle.net/hG99U/3/ as long as it's the first character we're checking, oh this is nice

Comment: You seemed to work the hardest, so if you want to update your answer to reflect my update I will give you credit.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=email]').on('keypress', function (e) {
    var re = /[A-Z0-9a-z@\._]/.test(e.key);
    if (!re) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: it works for me

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to write all the special characters into the regular expression that need to be prohibited, because there will be a large list, simple write the ones that are allowed because they are less(that you have already done and perhaps only one or two more characters viz. `DOT,UnderScore` are remaining).

The code you have used to test the validity of inputted character is already fine, which will verify the character to be out of  `[A-Z0-9a-z@]` only, probably you can make it `[A-Z0-9a-z@\._]` for other two characters.

```
keychar = String.fromCharCode(keynum);
regEx = /[A-Z0-9a-z@]/;
return regEx.test(keychar);
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  Oddly, however, the characters #$ still pass-through?

Comment: This is perfectly working, try typing `javascript:alert(/[A-Z0-9a-z@]/.test("$"));` in a browser's address bar directly, you will get false. Problem is in your testing code `regEx.test(keychar)`, try to rectify it, first try direct `return /[A-Z0-9a-z@]/.test("$");` in place of it.

Comment: Puneet try typing `javascript:alert(/[A-Z0-9a-z@]/.test("ascacasc$"));` in your browser to understand the problem (it should be false since it has an illigal character)

Comment: You told that you are testing a string of only single character, to test a string of more than one character, you need to modify your regex like this: `/[A-Z0-9a-z@]+/`

Comment: And infact you have to use `^regex$`, which signifies that from start till end, the valid characters are in regex only, so finally it becomes: `/^[A-Z0-9a-z@]+$/`

Comment: Well at least make sure it includes a dot then: `/^[A-Z0-9a-z@\.]+$/` but I think the OP wanted to specifically blacklist several characters rather than a whitelist...

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var email='1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.@_'
var bksp = 'backspace'
var alt = 'alt'


function alpha(e,allow) {
var k;
k=document.all?parseInt(e.keyCode): parseInt(e.which);
return (allow.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(k))!=-1);
}

// -->
</script>


<input type="text" onkeypress="return alpha(event,email+bksp+alt)" />
```