# For E-Mail validation this code not working can i know the reason

Tags: javascript

Check this. At `email field` its not accepting even single key stroke also. Upto my knowledge mistake there at `AllowRegex` variable its unable to validate what i enter in email field in form..

```
function mailonly(e) {
    var code;
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(code);
    var AllowRegex = /^[\ba-zA-Z0-9\s-._ ]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;
    if (AllowRegex.test(character))
        return true;
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Are you really trying to validate against a regex when the data is appearing character by character? This won't work. Wait until you have the entire address and then use the regex. If, of course, the regex itself works.

Comment: Do u know its even not allowing to enter single character...i can't press any key in email field in form...

Answer (score 1):

try to validate the email after the complete email address is written. I think you use `onblur` for that.

Also I notices that you allowed `\s` (white spaces) in the email which is not correct. You should use `\S` (CAP) instead. which is opposite of `\s`.

Also there should be a `\` before the `.` (DOT). `/^[\ba-zA-Z0-9\S-\._]`

Comment: Actual problem is in form Email field not allowing me to enter even single key,so that how can i enter entire email...

Comment: remove the `onkeypress` (or `onkeydown`, `onkeyup`) and call the JS on `onblur` event.

Answer (score 0):

AllowRegex check complete Email-Id not single character and you are checking text on every keypress.
check this it will help you [check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165976/validating-an-email-address-on-key-press-using-javascript-jquery) it.
another example is [jsfiddle.net/bKT9W/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/bKT9W/2/).

```
    function validateEmail() {

    var validEmail = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
    if (validEmail.test($('#user_email').val())) {
        $('.masked-check').fadeIn(300);
        $('#status').html('Valid Email!');
    }
    else {
        $('.masked-check').fadeOut(300);
        $('#status').html('INVALID Email!');
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you trid jsfiddle example? Its working [http://jsfiddle.net/bKT9W/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/bKT9W/2/)

Comment: you can do validation on `onblur` event using your regexp instead of `onkeypress` event.

Comment: Yes Mr.Pratik,but it's shown id attribute is undefined,at id="user_email" may its bcoz i m using struts framework...i didn't understand...

Comment: id="user_email" is id of your input tag for email id in your html.